# Local copy 'xxx' of the variable 'xxx' is never modified;

Tags: shared-ptr

```
shared_ptr<int> sp1(new int(10));
shared_ptr<int> sp3(sp1);
*sp3 = 20;
```

I wrote the code above, but clion advises me that 'Clang-Tidy: Local copy 'sp3' of the variable 'sp1' is never modified; consider avoiding the copy'；and clion modifies my code to below:

I want to konw why clion give me that advise
and why `const shared_ptr<int>& sp3(sp1);` is the best
thank you!

Comment: What language is this? C? C++? I don't know enough about either one to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying any large object generally costs more than just referencing it (, and the reference can sometimes be optimized by the compiler). **clang-tidy** is smart enough to detect that you never modify `sp3` and the copy can be avoided.

If you only wonder why **clang-tidy** gives you this suggestion, you can stop here, since it will give you the same suggestion whatever class you use. The following paragraphs explain how copying a shared pointer can be expensive.

This represents your original code:

```
      contains
sp3 --------------
 | copy of        \
 |                 \       ______________
 V    contains      \     |     ...      | points to
sp1 --------------------> | new int(10) -+----------> 10
                          |______________|
                            control block
```

By using `const shared_ptr<int>& sp3(sp1);` you create a reference to `sp1`, and you can still change the value the raw pointer points to. The `const &` only means you cannot modify `sp1` by `sp3`.

```
                             ______________
       &        contains    |     ...      | points to
sp3 ------>sp1 -----------> | new int(10) -+----------> 10
                            |______________|
                              control block
```

The control block is used for reference counting and ensures thread-safety by **atomic operations**, which costs much more time than just copying bytes. That's why you should only copy a `std::shared_ptr<?>` when you really need to. (e.g. Pass it to another thread or store it in a graph structure)

Comment: thank you very much! your answer is very clearly!
but i still have a question ` clang-tidy is smart enough to detect that you never modify sp3 and the copy can be avoided.` what modify mean,? sp3 point to other shared_ptr<int> object means modify sp3?

Comment: In your case, `sp3` doesn't point to but makes a copy of `sp1`. But either way (`const &` or copying) `sp3` and `sp1` in your code are unchanged, and only the integer value they point to is changed (by `*sp3 = 20;`). What I meant was that if you were to modify `sp3` (e.g., calling `reset()` method) and keep `sp1` unchanged, the copy was essential. But if you only call methods that can be done on `sp1`, then `sp3` is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes. By calling `reset()` you can change the internal object `sp3` points to, and it's a modification. But `reset()` only accept raw pointers to redirect, and when doing so, a new control block is created. `reset()` can also clear a shared pointer after which it contains `nullptr`.